# Mapping mouse position to transformation of Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an object, let's call it

```
<div class="myObject">foo</div>
```

which is obviously within the body tag.

I transform said object like this:

```
transform: perspective( 2000px ) rotateY( -15deg) rotateX( 15deg );
```

I also track the mouse position on mousemove like this:

```
var pageX = event.pageX;
var pageY = event.pageY;
```

Now I want to map the coordinates of my cursor onto the -15 to +15, while body "0" is -15 and body "maxwidth" represents +15.

I Can't just map the mouse position to the value because then I loose the relation.

How do I do that? When the cursor is centered on the window both values should be 0.

Thanks!

Comment: are you tracking the mouse move on the body or the myObject div? I am trying to recreate this in jsbin https://jsbin.com/bayirojejo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: okay, I now went with percentages, but how can I map my 0-100% to -15 and +15? https://jsbin.com/jaqimufafo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I cant seem to get the full width 15 to 15, but maybe this might help your idea sorry https://jsbin.com/hefodicoki/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I got it, thanks to this post:

https://gist.github.com/AugustMiller/85b54d49493bb71ba81e

```
            var pageX = event.pageX;
            var pageY = event.pageY;

            //console.log(pageX);
            //console.log(pageY);

            var numX = 0;
            var numY = 0;

            var bodyX = $('body').width();
            var bodyY = $('body').height();



            var rotX = (((pageX - bodyX) / (-15 - bodyX)) * -30)+15;
            var rotY = (((pageY - bodyY) / (-15 - bodyY)) * -30)+15;


            console.log('x: '+rotX);
            console.log('y: '+rotY);
```